# How to make this type safe?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a method(undefineAllLeafProperties) which sets undefined to all "leaf" properties so that while accessing any nested properties(parents of leaf properties) won't give any undefined exception.

ex:

```
class Person {
   name : string = 'default name';
   age : number = 0;
   address : { street : string, city : string } = { street : '', city : ''};
}
```

Calling undefineAllLeafProperties(new Person()); should give

```
{
 name : undefined,
age : undefined,
address : { 
            street : undefined,
            city : undefined
           }
}
```

The reason for the above requirement is because I need to fill the required properties only and remove all when passed to JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Problem : When calling recursively, its throwing an error

```
Argument of type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
  Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'object'.
    Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'object'.
```

How to solve this without using 'any'?

```
export function undefineAllLeafProperties<T extends object>(obj : T) : T {

    const keys : Array<keyof T> = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;

    keys.forEach(key => {
        if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            obj[key] = undefineAllLeafProperties(obj[key]); // recursively call the same function
        }
        else {
            obj[key] = undefined;
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to create an Address class and use it as the type of your address property? : address: Address   = { ... };

Comment: I can do that too but not sure how it helps. Still the error will be same is it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this expression does not act as a type guard:

```
typeof obj[key] === "object"
```

As far as i know there is no "clean" way to resolve this. Adding the `<any>` in the recursive call will resolve the error:

```
obj[key] = undefineAllLeafProperties(<any>obj[key])
```

(Even if you force the `object` typing, you will still have an issue because the function then will return `object` which is no longer assignable to `obj[key]`.)

Comment: Thanks for the note. Adding any is solving but wondering if there is any other option.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The following code is error-free and returns type-safe objects. The improvements I made are:

1. `Record<string, any>` over `object`, Record is more restrictive and it allows reassigning keys.
2. Mapped `Undefined<T>` type, so TypeScript knows all values will be undefined in the return type.
3. `as T[keyof T]`, TypeScript doesn't know what key we are assigning to because we use generics. The solution here is to cast it to `T[keyof T]` to reassure TS we know what we are doing (I wish there was a better solution for this, but I couldn't find any).

I used an interface in this example, but a class as in the question also works.

```js
interface Person {
  age: number;
  name: {
    first: string;
    last: string;
  };
}

const p: Person = {
  age: 9,
  name: {
    first: "First",
    last: "Last"
  }
};

type Undefined<T> = { [P in keyof T]: undefined };

export function undefineAllLeafProperties<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: T
): Undefined<T> {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key: keyof T) => {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      obj[key] = undefineAllLeafProperties(obj[key]) as T[keyof T];
    } else {
      obj[key] = undefined as T[keyof T];
    }
  });

  return obj;
}

const pu = undefineAllLeafProperties(p);
console.log(pu);
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-recursive-undefined-3vhy6

### Optional Chaining

In your question you mention:

> ...so that while accessing any nested properties(parents of leaf properties) won't give any undefined exception.

JavaScript and TypeScript have added a feature to solve exactly this problem, called **optional chaining**.

```js
let street = person?.address?.street;
```

In this example it will not throw an exception if either `person` or `address` is undefined, and just assign undefined to `street`.

If you are using TypeScript >= 3.7 you can use this syntax. Alternatively you can use Babel with the [optional chaining plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining).

Learn more here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: JavaScript and TypeScript have added a feature to solve exactly this problem, called optional chaining - Here i have case where i need to set the value rather than retrieving. Ex : I should be able to set directly (only street in address object) person.address.street and always address need to be defined a head.